# Cannot convert value of type 'WeatherViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Tags: swift4.2

I am trying to push navigationController to another view and i am getting this error "Cannot convert value of type 'WeatherViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'"

```
 extension RegionListViewController: SidebarViewDelegate {

  func sidebarDidSelectRow(row: Row) {
    blackScreen.isHidden = true
    blackScreen.frame = self.view.bounds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
      self.sidebarView.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: self.sidebarView.frame.height)
    }
    switch row {
    case .ethiopia:
      let vc = EthiopiaVC()
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    case .weather:
     let wV = WeatherViewController()
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(wV, animated: true)
    case .currency:
      print("Settings")
    case .Searchs:
      let sv = SearchViewController()
      **self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sv, animated: true)** error here
    case .feedbacks:
      print("Sign out")
    case .none:
      break

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure your custom view controllers are all subclasses of UIViewController?

Comment: thanks for the Tip . I just did that and it fixed

Comment: Glad to hear! I'll add it as an answer below so you can mark it completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your custom view controllers are all subclasses of `UIViewController`.